# Why is the order of topics in help center not always the same?

Tags: support, help-center, beta-sites

Almost all sites' Help Center pages follow this order in their Asking section:

- What topics can I ask about here?
- What types of questions should I avoid asking? .... etc.

But I found that some sites have different order. For example, see that for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help). Beta sites have often different order as follows:

- What types of questions should I avoid asking?
- What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?
- What topics can I ask about here?

However, some beta sites have order as explained first. If we consider for meta that it is because of on-topic is under construction, then after decided, it also sometimes not followed to same. For example, [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help) has 2<sup>nd</sup> mentioned order whereas [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) has 1<sup>st</sup> mentioned order though both have defined on-topics.

Why is the order of topics in help center not always the same?